# MySQL Query: Concatenate horizontally based on selected ids

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have a table 'table_name' with two columns like this:

```
table_name
------------
my_id | data
------|-----
  id1 | 312
  id1 | 523
  id1 | 128
  id2 | 239
  id2 | 479
  id2 | 121
  id3 | 639
  id3 | 429
  id3 | 131
  id4 | 473
  id4 | 872
  id4 | 662
  id4 | 174
  id4 | 272
```

I tried around a while and I now found a way to select the ids I want to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT my_id from table_name WHERE (my_id REGEXP 'id[234]')
```

This gives me the ids 'id2', 'id3' and 'id4'. How would I formulate a query that gives me my desired output, based on the selected ids as below?

```
id2 | id3 | id4
---------------
239 | 639 | 473
479 | 429 | 872
121 | 131 | 662
NaN | NaN | 174
NaN | NaN | 272
```

Comment: Why would you use `regexp` instead of `in ('id2', 'id3')` ?

Comment: This is just an example, the real ids are more complex and require a regular expression to get all the matching ids.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example so that no one has to guess what the real problem is?

Comment: In my opinion, this example is perfectly complete. You did not mention what you don't understand. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: One potential problem I see is is what happens if the two sets of IDs are not the same size?  Also, what relation are you using to connect, for example, `239` with `639`, or `121` with `131`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the question. Is it understandable now?

Comment: "require a regular expression to get all the matching ids" That sounds like a bad idea :-(

Comment: Why does this sound like a bad idea? How would you optimize this?

Comment: Relational data doesn't have an intrinsic "order" to it, so if your table really only has those two columns, it will be difficult to match the "first" id2 value with the "first" id3 value and such.

Comment: @Tim Lehner: This could possibly be an answer to my question but I can't believe that this is not possible with sql...

Comment: Well but it seems so since nobody has an idea. Thank you all!

Comment: do you have another table that connected to the my_id column?? because i can see is that you loop the data base of what data(column) included

Comment: I think i can answer your question

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the question... You can assume that I only have one table as above... I will check in later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table really only has those two columns and there is no related data that can be used to order the `data` column like you have shown, then there is no good way to achieve the ordering you're looking for.

Relational data doesn't have any intrinsic "order" to it, even if you've inserted that data in a particular order or displayed it in a certain way here. If your table really only has those two columns, it will be difficult to match the "first" id2 value with the "first" id3 value and so on to get to your desired output. We could potentially rank them in a query and match them based upon that rank (ascending or descending) or even provide some random order capability, but there is no documented (i.e. *reliable*) way to get the order that you've provided.

While a table does have a physical order to the underlying bits in storage, and some products allow you to access them via a physical `rowid` (Oracle), no RDBMS that I know of (including MySql) guarantees the order in which the rows will be returned unless an `order by` clause is used in your select statement. This is literally by design and is considered a "feature" that came out of E.F. Codd's research.

Answer (score 1):

First make a function that select distinct of the id's

```
public function get_id_of_table_name() {
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT my_id ';
    $sql .= 'FROM table_name ';

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $result = $query->row();
    foreach ($result as $key => $value)
    {
      $result->data = $this->get_data($result->my_id);
    }

    return ( $query->num_rows() ) ? $result : FALSE;
}
```

And create the second function that will gather all the data's base on what id's

```
public function get_data($my_id) {
    $params = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT data ';
    $sql .= 'FROM table_name ';
    $sql .= 'WHERE my_id = ? ';

    $params[] = $my_id;

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);

    $result_data = $query->result();
    $data = [];

    foreach ($result_data as $result)
    {
        array_push($data, $result->data);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

You can put a where clause in the first function if you want.

```
$sql .= 'WHERE my_id = ? ';
```

and add the params

```
$params[] = $my_id;
```

You can also add parameters my_id as array in the first function so that you can get what id you want to get

```
$id = ["id2","id3","id4"];

public function get_id_of_table_name($id) {
    $params = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT my_id ';
    $sql .= 'FROM table_name ';
    $sql .= 'WHERE 1 ';

    foreach ($id as $my_id)
    {
        $sql .= 'OR (my_id = ?) ';

        $params[] = $my_id;
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);

    $result = $query->row();
    foreach ($result as $key => $value)
    {
      $result->data = $this->get_data($result->my_id);
    }

    return ( $query->num_rows() ) ? $result : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Will this actually give the desired ordered output in the question?

Comment: @Michael Amaleona: I really appreciate your work but I was hoping to find a simpler solution. I thought that this is also possible in SQL with a few lines... I think I better change my design since SQL does not support these operations easily. To you as a person it might not be worth it to spend so much time to gain 10 stackoverflow reputation credits. In the beginning it was quite easy to gain reputation here but today I think it has become too hard and it is not worth the time. You might be better off to go for some Udacity courses if you want to get some reputation but that is just a guess.